# How to check if the current datetime retrieved from database has pass midnight in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose datetime I retrieved from database is --> 2020-05-23 00:06:22AM

I want to check whether this retrieved datetime has passed midnight of the same day. That is I want to compare using C#

2020-05-23 00:06:22AM with 2020-05-23 11:59:59PM ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How come any date doesn't pass the midnight?

Comment: do you want to compare 2020-05-23 00:06:22AM with 2020-05-23 11:59:59PM or 2020-05-24 00:06:22AM with 2020-05-23 11:59:59PM? As your comparison will always return false because you are comparing same day date.

Comment: @JohnyL hi johnny, it will of course pass! once I pass I need to reset the counter. I am not sure how to check in order to reset that's why

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to compare same day date with mid night time but remember it will always return False.

```
DateTime dateTimeInput =Convert.ToDateTime("2020-05-23 00:06:22 AM");

bool ispassed = dateTimeInput > Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeInput.ToShortDateString() + " 11:59:59 PM");
```

I hope you want to compare 2020-05-23 00:06:22 AM date with current date(today) midnight. in this case below code should work:

```
DateTime dateTimeInput =Convert.ToDateTime("2020-05-23 00:06:22 AM");

bool ispassed = dateTimeInput > Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " 11:59:59 PM");
```

Comment: hi thanks, the second one did what I intend to do. but then I realise its not what I need to do. what I need to do is to reset the variable whenever it hits midnight. Any idea how to do that? if midnight has not passed, then the variable will keep on incrementing

Comment: Whatever you want to reset put in if(ispassed) condition. Eg. If(ispassed){ x="reset"}.write this line just below ispassed statement in my solution. If it helps mark useful